# Perl program to take two different inputs through STDIN

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl program:

```
    print "Enter the filename:";
    $filename = readline STDIN;

    print "Enter the string to be compared";
    $string1 = readline STDIN;
```

To combine these two inputs in one go, I did the following:

```
    print "Enter the filename and string to be compared:";
    my $input1 = readline STDIN; 
    my @name = split(' ',$input1); //split the input parameters by space
    $filename = $name[0];
    $string1 = $name[1];
    chomp $string1;
```

This is functional code,I wanted to know if there is any other way to implement more optimized version for this logic?

Thanks,
DD

Comment: define *optimized*!

Comment: I would not recomend to you to optimize in such way. What you will do if filename will contain whitespace? Logic will increase. Look @mkHun unswer.

Comment: Have a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's about as optimised as you get. Don't bother trying to hand optimise code until you're sure you need to. Given this is a wait for IO, it will just not matter, because IO is slower than anything you're doing in code.

But if you meant more *concise*:

```
print "Enter the filename and string to be compared:";
chomp ( my ( $filename, $string )  = split ' ', <> );
```

This takes `<>` - which is the magic filehandle, and reads *either* STDIN or a filename specified on command line. (Works like `grep`/`sed`/`awk`).

We split it on a space, in a scalar context - and then hand the values from split to a list assignment to `$filename` and `$string`. Which is then chomped to strip linefeeds.

Answer (score 2):

What about [kite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Kite)  From perl secret

```
use warnings;
use strict;
print "Enter the filename and string to be compared:";
chomp( my @ar = (~~<>, ~~<> ) );
print @ar;
```

Comment: Whilst clever, I am not really convinced that anything in 'perl secret' is something you should be using in real  code, simply because it's obscure.

Comment: `scalar(<>)` or `"".<>` would be less "secret". // Note that reading from a file handle after it returned EOF is a no-no, so this approach is inherently flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code bellow with the 
`comand:perl your_script.pl -file_name 'some_file' -string 'some_string'

```
use Getopt::Long;

my ( $file_name, $string );
GetOptions(
'file_name=s' => \$file_name,
'string=s' => \$string,
) or die "Could not parse options";

if($file_name eq $string )
{
print "The file name is the same as the string\n";
}else{
print "Not a match\n";
}
```